# Hibernate ManyToOne save. Save Parent without Child. But Child should be searched according a particular attribute

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

i simply want to save a parent entity with the proper foreign key to a relation. For this relation i just want to give a particular attribute, this should be found, retrieve the id and set the id to the parent as foreign key. An example follows below.

My entities:

```
PEOPLE(
  PEOPLE_ID number(19) PRIMARY KEY, 
  NAME varchar(255), 
  TYPE_ID number(19), 
  FOREIGN KEY (TYPE_ID) REFERENCES TYPE(TYPE_ID)
);
```

```
TYPE(
  TYPE_ID number(19) PRIMARY KEY, 
  NAME varchar(255) unique
);
```

PEOPLE is related to TYPE. So that many People can have one TYPE, and one TYPE can have many PEOPLE. But i'm only interested into the direction of PEOPLE to TYPE.

The TYPE-Table is prefilled with some values. There is no need to insert or update data.
TYPE-Values 
1, Student
2, Teacher
...

PEOPLE Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PEOPLE")
public class PeopleDBO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name= "PEOPLE_ID")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name= "TYPE_ID", referencedColumnName="TYPE_ID")
    private TypeDBO type;

    //getters and setters
}
```

TYPE Entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "TYPE")
public class TypeDBO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "TYPE_ID")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    //getters and setters
}
```

I'm using JPA standard repositories to save the entities

The Code:

```
final TypeDBO type = new TypeDBO();
type.setName("Teacher");

final PeopleDBO people = new PeopleDBO();
people.setName("George");
people.setType(type);

peopleRepository.save(people);
```

In the code above i try to just set the TYPE.NAME and hibernate should search the corrected record by itself, find the correct id and peopleRepository just save the parent. I think i have two problems here. First of all i get this Error Message, because TYPE.NAME is unique and hibernate tries to insert an already existing name:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_9 ON PUBLIC.TYPE(TYPE_ID) VALUES 2"; SQL statement:
insert into TYPE (NAME, TYPE_ID) values (?, ?) [23505-199]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

And second problem will be (as soon as the first is solved) that hibernate dont know how which attribute should be the searched one.

OK i could write following code and read the TYPE first, but i want to avoid it. Because is just a simple sample. My real project has 7 of these TYPES, and i think it will be really inefficient to read all the types first to save one parent.

I want avoid this code:

```
final TypeDBO type typeRepository.findByName("Teacher");

final PeopleDBO people = new PeopleDBO();
people.setName("George");
people.setType(type);

peopleRepository.save(people);
```

Do you have an idea how to solve it, or some keywords so that i can do more detailed research?

many thanks in advance!
D.

Answer (score 0):

What you wish for is not really possible with JPA and I would advise you if you want to keep this style of programming to do this rather with JDBC than JPA because that style is not what JPA is meant for but this is very easily doable in JDBC. JPA wants you to think in Entities and not in database columns (that's what JPA means with "abstraction") therefore your last example is exactly the way JPA is meant to be used by his creators.

But of course you can replace your `@ManyToOne` relationship with a basic `String` column that represents your foreign key but then you have to establish the relationship between objects at runtime yourself, i.e. on loading the `PeopleDBO` you would have to load the respective `TypeDBO` yourself using a second query and then probably setting on the `PeopleDBO` object.

Comment: Ok, that is a statement JPA is not intended to work in that way. Let me see, either i will use the JPA enumeration functionality and write all my TYPES directly in the parent entity as a string or i implement the second way (that i tried to avoid) but with a proper caching. Thanks a lot!

Comment: JPA already contains caching functionality (see https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/Cacheable) when you load entities by their primary key, so maybe you can leverage that to reduce the number of actual SQL queries (I did this a few times in different projects).

Answer (score 0):

As you said Type entity going to populated with predefined values. So while saving the  Popele entity you need to map the existing type record based on the type value

But in below code you are trying to create new Type record always. Instated of that you need to get the type record from DB based on the Name and that entity you need to map while saving the Poeple record.

final TypeDBO type = new TypeDBO();
type.setName("Teacher");

similar to below you can get the record
TypeDBO type  = featchByName("Teacher")

then set this value while saving the people record.
people.setType(type);

Comment: That's exactly what OP wrote he don't want to to.